# Spring Visualisation in Eclipse - UML Diagrams etc - Open Source

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, uml, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

There are a few different Eclipse plugins out there or other Java IDEs which seem to have good Spring visualizations such as MyEclipse and IntelliJ, however these products all required a license.

I was wondering if there were any plugins out there which are open source which provide visualization of Spring such as the spring context xml and work with annotations or even Camel Routes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you take a look at [Spring IDE](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts)?
It has visualizations for `bean.xml` files. I have no idea about Camel Routes, but Spring Integration is supported.